# Duplicate sources in sources.list

Tags: debian, linux-mint

I work on Linux Mint Debian Edition 2 "Betsy."

Upon running

```
      sudo apt-get update
```

I get the following error code at the end of the output

```
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://security.debian.org/           

jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists   

/security.debian.org_dists_jessie_updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages)

W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates

/contrib amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists

/security.debian.org_dists_jessie_updates_contrib_binary-amd64_Packages)

W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates

/non-free amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists

/security.debian.org_dists_jessie_updates_non-free_binary-amd64_Packages)

W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://security.debian.org/ 

jessie/updates/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists   

/security.debian.org_dists_jessie_updates_main_binary-i386_Packages)

W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates

/contrib i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists

/security.debian.org_dists_jessie_updates_contrib_binary-i386_Packages)

W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates

/non-free i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists

/security.debian.org_dists_jessie_updates_non-free_binary-i386_Packages)

W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

However, my etc/apt/sources.list file looks fine. Here it is,

```
  #/etc/apt/sources.list

  deb http://http.debian.net/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free

  deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look in `/etc/sources.d` for additional files used by `apt-get` and friends.

Personally, I zero out `/etc/sources.list` and move its contents into `/etc/sources.d` so I can easily identify not only stable or testing, but also third-party additions such as those provided by Google Chrome.